# Silverlight4 DataTemplates

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datatemplate

I have a ItemsControl with its ItemsSource bound to a collection, additionally I have a ItemTemplateSelector set.

It works well however the DataTemplateSelector only allows me to access the items bound by ItemsSource, however I want to use the Parents DataContext to make the decision on what item template should be used.

Is this achievable in SL4??

If so how can it be achieved??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response @Xin but I managed to resolve my problem by doing the following.

```
        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTemplate dt = null;

        switch ((DataContext as PlanViewModel).Plan.Status)
        {
            case Infrastructure.Services.Web.PlanStatus.Appraisal:
                dt = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["Appraisal"];
                break;
            case Infrastructure.Services.Web.PlanStatus.Maintenance:
                dt = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["Maintenance"];
                break;
            case Infrastructure.Services.Web.PlanStatus.Setting:
                dt = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["Setting"];
                break;
        }

        itemsControl1.ItemTemplate = dt;
    }
```

Comment: yes this definitely works. what i thought was to do it in an mvvm fashion without any code behind. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

Name your layout root 'LayoutRoot', then you can do

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.SomeTextInParent, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
```

in your item template.

Comment: Thanks for response, but how does this allow me to make a decision on what template should be selected?

Comment: can you provide me with more info that why you need this DataTemplateSelector? alternitively you can just use one template with different inner Grids and then toggle the Visibility based on your criteria.